# Show that there is $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ for which is $A' \subset (A')'$, in topology of left rays on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that there is set $A$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ for which is $A' \subset (A')'$, considering topology of left rays on $\mathbb{R}$.

I can not think of any set. Seems trivial(?). I tried multiple sets but each time I get $A' = (A')'$.

Comment: What do you mean by $A'$?

Comment: And do you mind telling how the topology of 'left rays' is defined?

Comment: @Cornman $A'$ is set of all accumulation points of set $A$.

Comment: @Cornman that is topology where sets $< - \infty, a >$ where $a \in \mathbb{R} $ are opened

Comment: @Cornman isn't it $ (\emptyset)' = (\emptyset) = ((\emptyset)')' $ ?

Comment: Yes, thats why I deleted that comment. I didnt notice you wanted a real subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following definition for $A'$:

We say that $x\in A'$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for any open neighborhood $U$ such that $x\in U$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a\not = x$ and $a\in U$ (The assumption that $a\not = x$ is going to be extremely important).

With respect to this definition we can take: $A=\{0\}$. 
Then $A'=(0,\infty)$ as every neighborhood of $x>0$ will contain $0$. However $A'' = [0,\infty)$.

Without the assumption that $a\not = x$ I believe you can prove that $A''\subseteq A'$.

Comment: I think that in this case $A' = \left[0 , \infty )$ because whenever you take neighborhood $U$ around 0 (which means $0 \in Int(U)$, where $ Int$ means interior) $U \cap A$ is non-empty set.

Comment: @user560461 $x$ cannot be a limit point (accumulation point) of $\{x\}$, so Yanko is correct.